# How to change the order of startup applications?

Tags: startup

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick.

I have a long list of startup applications as you can see here:
[image: startup apps]

I have added an entry for Google Chrome, and I would like Google Chrome to start like first of all the other applications... How is this done?

Comment: Try giving it a name higher in the alphabetical order. I usually want my conky to start last so I name it ZZZ-Conky and that works for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These will start in alphabetical order, so you can name the startup application `0-Chrome` to start it before the others.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a startup script and make it look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
app1 &
app2 &
sleep 2s
app3 &
```

Make it executable and add an entry in the startup applications like:

```
sh /path/to/startupscript.sh
```

Comment: If you make it executable, you do not need to add `sh` before it. `bash` != `sh`, so `bash /path/to/script.sh` is something different than `sh /path/to/script.sh`.