# Command to list systemd services that run on startup in the order in which they run?

Tags: boot, command-line, startup, systemd, services

Is there a `command` to list systemd services that run on startup in the order in which they run? I'm using 18.04

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49274/how-to-change-the-order-of-startup-applications) will give you the answer to what you're looking for.

Comment: By "services" do you specifically mean systemd services? Or something else? Are you simply curious? Or is there some issue that you believe such a list will help you investigate or solve?

Comment: @user535733 I do mean systemd services, my apologies. If have a unit file I need running after everything else runs, so once I know what the last thing is I can set said unit file to "after=lastservice.service". Can you help me with this?

Comment: Why does it need to run "after everything else?" For example, anacron runs a few *minutes* after everything else. Should your job run after anacron?  apt.daily runs some random time up to an hour after startup. Should your job run after apt.daily?

Comment: @user535733 bear with me, I just started using LInux 4 days ago. I need it to run specifically after all of my audio/microphone services run. I am unable to pinpoint exactly which audio/microphone services at the time of writing this comment, so I am just making it run after everything. I was unaware of anacron/apt.daily. You're knowledgeable it seems, what do you recommend I run it after?

Comment: Advice: Try having your job depend upon systemd's default.target. That's among the last targets after startup on a desktop system, and should be a very long time after hardware/audio is up (audio.target). Try to be patient when volunteers are trying to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

Run in the terminal:

```
systemd-analyze dump > ~/SystemdAnalyzeDump.txt
```

and to view it, run in the terminal:

```
gedit ~/SystemdAnalyzeDump.txt
```

or if you prefer a graphical representation, run in the terminal:

```
systemd-analyze plot > ~/SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg
```

and to view it, run in the terminal:

```
eog ~/SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg
```

**Notice** that the `--user` option can be used with the above commands like `systemd-analyze --user dump ...` and `systemd-analyze --user plot ...` to show user units instead.

Comment: On 18.04 it (GNOME Image Viewer 3.28.1) it seems we have [this fixed bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg/-/issues/237) on librsvg. Not sure since which version is fixed.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times, it's so useful! One remark, I found that parts of the svg graph may get drawn outside the "canvas", and EOG (Eye Of the Gnome, aka image viewer app) will not show these parts outside of the page area. Viewing it with an SVG editor app, like Inkscape, however shows all the parts even those outside of the page area.