# How to run a bash script while Ubuntu is starting up on tty

Tags: boot, bash, tty

My grub doesn't have "quiet splash" so it displays text while booting, and I want to run "neofetch -L" just before it displays "Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a custom service to run your script at boot by following the steps below.

**Firstly,** run the following command in the terminal to create and edit a shell script file in your home directory:

```
nano ~/MyScript.sh
```

**Secondly,** copy and paste the following code into the editor, **( `neofetch -L` is just an example )** and save it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> :

```
#!/bin/bash

neofetch -L
```

**Thirdly,** make the shell script file **executable** by running the following command in the terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/MyScript.sh
```

**Fourthly,** create and edit a custom **systemd** service to run the shell script at boot by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/MyCustomService.service
```

**Fifthly,** copy and paste the following code into the editor, replace `USERNAME` with **your username** and save it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> :

```
[Unit]
Description=My Custom Service
Before=motd-news.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/USERNAME/MyScript.sh
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Sixthly,** start the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start MyCustomService
```

**Seventhly,** enable the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl enable MyCustomService
```

**Finally,** reboot your system.

---

If for any reason you want to **undo this solution**, please run the following commands in the terminal one after the other in the same sequence below:

1. `sudo systemctl stop MyCustomService`
2. `sudo systemctl disable MyCustomService`
3. `sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/MyCustomService.service`
4. `rm ~/MyScript.sh`

---

**Notice:**

- `neofetch` must be installed on your system in order for the above example script to work. It can be installed like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install neofetch
  ```
- `StandardOutput=journal+console` will enable printing output from your script on screen.
- You can change when the custom service starts executing during boot by specifying in the service file under `[Unit]` the [`Before=` and `After=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=) system services so that your custom service will run after and / or before certain system services. Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200743/command-to-list-systemd-services-that-run-on-startup-in-the-order-in-which-they/1200749#1200749) to list the system services in the order they are run.

**Becareful:**

Test your script first and make sure it executes in a timely correct way to avoid delay or lock-up during boot.

Comment: Good response! Only problem is that it didn't work, the bash file runs normally if I run it on command line but when it's booting the logo doesn't appear, I actually saw the service being started like wayy after the welcome message but saw no logo appearing even logging on tty. I checked the service with systemctl status and it actually printed the logo there instead of tty, I'll try viewing a way to force it to print into tty.

Comment: Got it to show in the TTY! looks amazing yet its kinda sad I couldn't get it where i wanted to. I'm still happy with the result!

Comment: @ThatXPUser That is great, well done. I have updated the answer with extra information that can help.

Answer (score 0):

`MOTD` or message of the day is what you seek from the description.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-welcome-message-motd-on-ubuntu-18-04-server

Comment: I didn't mean a motd. when Ubuntu starts starting services it says "Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" then it follows with the hostname being set, I want to make the program run before that gets printed on the screen. I can provide a photo if you still don't get what I mean.