# systemd PATH not working consistently

Tags: systemd, paths

I have a very simple `systemd` service:

```
[Unit]
Description=throttle service

[Service]
ExecStart=%h/.local/bin/throttle --server
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The executed service runs the command `mbsync [something]` in a python `subprocess` with `shell=False`.

I have 3 copies of `mbsync` installed:

```
❯ which -a mbsync
/home/fbence/.local/bin/mbsync
/home/fbence/.local/bin/mbsync
/usr/bin/mbsync
/bin/mbsync
```

Running `mbsync` from the login shell will obviously run the top one in `~/.local`. If I manually start the `systemd` service, as in `systemctl --user start throttle.service` it also picks up this one. If I reboot my system, then it seems to pick up one of the other (older) versions as I see errors in `journalctl`, where it is trying to access the config file for older version. If I manually stop and restart the service (`systemctl --user stop/start`) it works again correctly.

Why is this not consistent? What's the difference between me starting it and it starting on boot? How do I fix this to work also on boot?

**Update**

After some debugging I found that `/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session` logs some info about running `dbus-update-activation-environment`. I tested and adding an `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30` solves the issue. So now my question is actually: how do I setup the service to wait for this to happen in a less hacky way?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised it works when you start the service manually, since AFAIK systemd user units do not inherit environment variables set in places like `~/.profile` (which is where Ubuntu adds ~/.local/bin to the PATH). You could try creating a custom `~/.config/environment.d/` file containing the modified PATH as described here [Environment variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User#Environment_variables)

Comment: @steeldriver they don't but it seems `dbus-update-activation-environment` can set some stuff, but I can't figure out what I need to wait on.

Comment: You might want to use `WantedBy=graphical-session.target` instead of `WantedBy=default.target` or use `After=graphical-session.target`  or both for example.

Comment: @fbence ah! interesting yes that would explain it

Comment: @steeldriver You're absolutely right about system and user units cannot reference each other but that one is the "current graphical user session target"  `systemctl --user status graphical-session.target`

Comment: it looks like that target is never started for me @Raffa, probably because I have Regolith on top of Ubuntu ... I'll have to investigate a bit more I guess.

Comment: @Raffa ah my bad I was confusing `graphical-session.target` with `graphical.target`

Comment: @steeldriver I too confuse them and others all the time :D ... fbence You might find [Command to list systemd services that run on startup in the order in which they run?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1200743/968501) helpful in identifying the order in which the user units are run on your system..

Comment: @Raffa nice one, thanks, I will investigate!