# Order of startup programs

Tags: ubuntu-mate, startup-applications

It is my understanding that startup programs are run in alphabetical order.

I wanted to test that and wrote some scripts and put them in the Startup Programs.

Yet, Z_Last_Startup.sh runs first?

Why is that?

```
Time when /home/andy/bin/Z_Last_Startup.sh ran is:
10:18:11 am 08/31/22
Time when /home/andy/bin/0_Play_Relax_Music.sh ran is:
10:18:19 am 08/31/22

Z_Last_Startup.sh

Startup_LogFile="/home/andy/Downloads/Startup_Programs.txt"

# Name of script that this is
echo Time when $0 >> $Startup_LogFile ran is:
date +"%I:%M:%S %P %D"  >> $Startup_LogFile
```

Comment: 0 is not part of my alfabet you probably meant asci ;-)  "startup applications" in the old days (2007?) it was sorted by session number. And I remember you could add a number from 1-50 to give priority but that is long gone. Any recent source on the "alphabetial order"?  I would assume the answer is "no, it is done parallel not sequential".  I have no idea why "startup apps" has to wait for one to be finished. You can do that by using " && " between the 2.

Comment: This was my source. https://askubuntu.com/questions/49274/how-to-change-the-order-of-startup-applications @Rinzwind

Comment: hmm... too old You need a source that uses Wayland (Wayland also came with changes to almost all of Ubuntu)

Comment: Ok. I may add a short delay to other startup programs so my script that plays music runs first. @Rinzwind